# What is a right triangle with its sides on x and y axis called?

Tags: terminology, triangles

What is a right triangle with its sides on x and y axis called?

Is there a specific term/name used for those triangles?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L9E3.png)

I asked this because I couldn't find a name for those triangles, so I wonder if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a right triangle, it does not matter whether zero, one, or two legs (the sides adjacent to the right angle) are on the $x,y$ axes. If the legs are equal, it is an isosceles right triangle. If all sides are different, it is a scalene right triangle. A scalene right triangle with integers for all sides is a  Pythagorean triple. I know of no other names.